# Emmeans, pairs, contrasts, and all different p-values

Tags: r, p-value, lsmeans

The main regression formula I am using is as follows (Both the Group and Time variables are binary):

```
lmer.fit <- lmerTest::lmer(corrmcc ~ Group * Time + (1|ID), 
                           data = sm.dat)
summary(lmer.fit)

# Fixed effects:
#                   Estimate Std. Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)         429.92      36.14  65.74  11.896   <2e-16 ***
# GroupTTNS           -37.75      51.64  65.74  -0.731    0.467    
# TimeEoS             -55.68      34.92  40.36  -1.595    0.119    
# GroupTTNS:TimeEoS   -23.23      50.47  40.73  -0.460    0.648
```

As you can see, the Time variable (or TimeEoS) has a p-value of > 0.05. That is, there is no significant difference in the outcome between the two time points.

Then I applied the *emmeans* function with a bar (|) for a post-hoc analysis as follows:

```
pairs(emmeans(lmer.fit, ~ Time | Group)) 
Group = Control:
 contrast       estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Baseline - EoS     55.7 35.0 42.0   1.592  0.1189

Group = TTNS:
 contrast       estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Baseline - EoS     78.9 36.5 42.7   2.161  0.0364
```

Here, we can observe that for the TTNS group, the difference between the baseline and EoS is statistically significant (i.e., p-value = 0.0364, < 0.05).

However, when I applied the same function but with an asterisk (*), I obtained an opposite result as follows:

```
pairs(emmeans(lmer.fit, ~ Time * Group))
 contrast                         estimate   SE   df t.ratio p.value
 **Baseline Control - EoS Control       55.7 35.0 42.0   1.592  0.3940**
 Baseline Control - Baseline TTNS     37.8 51.6 66.9   0.731  0.8843
 Baseline Control - EoS TTNS         116.7 53.4 71.2   2.184  0.1376
 EoS Control - Baseline TTNS         -17.9 52.8 69.8  -0.340  0.9864
 EoS Control - EoS TTNS               61.0 54.6 73.6   1.118  0.6797
 **Baseline TTNS - EoS TTNS             78.9 36.5 42.7   2.161  0.1508**
```

Here, the difference between the baseline and EoS in the TTNS group is not significant with a p-value of 0.15.

I am sure that I am missing something, but I am having trouble finding what is causing the differences. Any suggestions and comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that `emmeans()` corrects *p* values for [multiple comparisons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-comparisons/info). Your first call to the function only involved 2 comparisons; the second call involved 6 comparisons. The extra number of comparisons means that the reported, multiplicity-corrected, *p* values are larger in the second call even though the estimate, SE, df, and t.ratio values are the same for the 2 comparisons that are the same in both calls.

See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/425129/28500) by the package's author for discussion about how the package chooses the comparisons to treat as multiple comparisons for this correction. It also links to the package's [vignette on comparisons](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html).

Also, consider the advice that the package's author provides in [one of the FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/FAQs.html#anova):

> First of all, you should not be making binary decisions of “significant” or “nonsignificant.” This is a simplistic view of *P* values that assigns an unmerited magical quality to the value 0.05. It is suggested that you just report the *P* values actually obtained, and let your readers decide how significant your findings are in the context of the scientific findings.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, @EdM ! When I added adjust = "none" option (i.e., pairs(emmeans(lmer.fit, ~ Time * Group), adjust = "none")), I was able to obtain the same p-values!

Comment: Hi @EdM . I have one follow-up question. In the main model, the p-value for 'Time' is 0.119. Based on this result (although I agree that making a binary decision based on the p-value is a matter of controversy), can we conclude that there is no significant difference in the outcome between the two time points? However, the post-hoc analysis reveals that specifically for the TTNS group, the difference between the baseline and EoS is statistically significant (i.e., an unadjusted p-value of 0.0364). Is this the correct conclusion to report?

Comment: Or... Is it incorrect to perform a post-hoc analysis if the interaction term is not significant?

Comment: @KLee it's tricky to interpret any of the individual coefficients in a model with interactions. It's possible, for example, for an overall evaluation of `Time` that includes the contribution from its interaction term to be "significant" even if neither its individual coefficient nor the interaction coefficient are"significant." What's most important here is whether you had a specific hypothesis about `Baseline - EoS` in `TTNS` before looking at the data. If so, then there might not be a need for multiple-comparison correction. Otherwise, you should be correcting.

Comment: @KLee if your primary interest is in a set of pairwise comparisons, there is no need to evaluate the overall model "significance" or that of any particular coefficients. See [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179826/28500) from the author of `emmeans`.